# Sqlite or Mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite, html, persistence

I am creating an online OS and to save apps that are installed I would use a database
and [persistence.js](http://persistencejs.org/); which database is the best for that use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends on your audience - if you have a lot of users you're going to want a dedicated daemon - so MySQL, Postgres and many others - however if it's just for you I'd use SQLite. You can always migrate later on rather than worrying about this now.